# Self referential structs for trees in C99

Tags: c, struct, tree

I am attempting to produce a hierarchical tree from textual data using C99. My aim is to ultimately render a diagram akin to the following parse tree.

[image: Parse Tree]

I am familiar with the concept of a linked list, but less so with its implementation in C as I come from a Java background. I am attempting to implement a tree data structure, which should not be substantially more complicated than a linked list.

I am trying to create a dynamic array list whose size may be updated as the number of child nodes changes. I have independently tested my code for this section (after replacing `struct node*` with `int*`).

```
typedef struct {
  struct node* array;
  int used;
  int size;
} node_array;
```

Next, I wish to define a struct to house the node itself and pointers to its parent and children. For the root node in my tree, the depth is set to 0, so the logic of my program should prevent the need of locating its parent.

```
typedef struct node {
  int depth;
  char* content;
  struct node* parent;
  node_array* children;
} node;
```

I receive a collection of two errors and a warning informing me that `struct node*` and `node*` are incompatible.

```
main.c: In function ‘array_insert’:
main.c:43:33: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct node’ from type ‘node *’
   43 |   array->array[array->used++] = element;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~
main.c: In function ‘print_tree’:
main.c:115:37: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘print_tree’
  115 |     print_tree(root->children->array[i], depth + 1);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
      |                                     |
      |                                     struct node
main.c:99:23: note: expected ‘node *’ but argument is of type ‘struct node’
   99 | void print_tree(node* root, int depth) {
      |                 ~~~~~~^~~~
```

Comment: Seems you forgot to post the code

Comment: Ask yourself, "Is it an array of structs or is it an array of pointers to structs?"

Comment: Look closely at the compiler warning, and then at what you said about it. A `struct node` is *not* a `struct node *`. It should have been `print_tree(&root->children->array[i], depth + 1);`, mind the `&`.

Comment: Rather than call the list of child nodes `array` use a meaningful name like `children`. Code should try to be self-documenting